# Is there no other way to remove the "7 day purchase" market ban other than spending money?

Tags: steam, steam-community-market

I recently got back to Steam after a long time and my marketplace has been made unavailable due to my not having a purchase between 7 days and 1 year old.

I read the FAQ site and it says I can remove it by making a game/DLC purchase. Is this the only way to get market privileges back? Do I have to spend money?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, you have to make some sort of purchase. [From Steam's help pages](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1047-edfm-2932#purchase):

"No Purchase Older Than 7 Days
Your account must have a successful purchase older than 7 days, but not older than a year in order to access the Community Market. The purchase of wallet funds, games, DLCs and software meet this requirement. Activating a Steam Wallet Code or Gift Card on your account to add funds to your Steam Wallet also meet this requirement. Retail CD key activation and gift purchases do not satisfy this requirement.

Any purchase that is charged back on your account will reset this restriction. Only purchases after the most recent chargeback will be considered for purposes of this restriction."

Comment: So what's the point of this restriction? It seems to me that younger users such as children without credit cards simply can't use the store in this case.

Comment: It is for security/fraud reasons they introduced this restriction due to the marketplace trading and how it works via steam. This way hacked accounts with expensive items can't trade to a new account to sell via steam or external website and then dump the new account and forget about it. This 'ties' an account to payment details and if this is a stolen card it will be reversed (hopefully) within 7 days which will then reset the 7 day restriction.